# Deny Folder Renaming

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2011

I have a folder in a shared network path which I want used as a template -- It contains many subfolders with naming conventions. This folder is meant  for users to copy, and then rename their newly created copy.

What I do not want is a user **renaming** my template folder. Thus, I want to deny the permission to rename the folder.

It was my understanding that to deny renaming you simply had to deny the delete permissions; but this appears to be incorrect.

I am not the owner of the folder, the folder is set to Read-only, and I am STILL able to rename with the follow permissions:

- Traverse folder / execute file
- List folder / read data
- Read attributes
- Read extended attributes
- Read permissions

What permissions must I remove, or what can I do to prevent the folder from being renamed so that users may only look at the folder and copy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need to set these permissions on the *parent* folder of the one you're trying to protect.

Comment: After reading this I noticed my template folder can be renamed, but its subfolder are protected from being renamed. This is silly though as I do not want to put my template folder under a parent folder for the rename permissions to work; it would needlessly complicate my template folder. I guess I have no choice though.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate Delete permissions.  One of them is applied to the current folder, the other is applied to the parent folder but they both affect the current folder.  As `RobM` stated, you need to make sure the parent folder does **not** have the "Delete Subfolders and Files" permission applied to "This Folder" **and** you need to make sure the template folder does **not** have the "Delete" permission applied to "This Folder".  If either of those permissions exist (and aren't denied) then renaming is still possible.

Here's a good description of those two permissions from http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm

> **Delete Subfolders and Files**
>
> > Allows or denies deleting subfolders and files, even if the Delete permission has not been granted on the subfolder or file.
>
> **Delete**
>
> > Allows or denies deleting the file or folder. If you don't have Delete permission on a file or folder, you can still delete it if you
> >     have been granted Delete Subfolders and Files on the parent folder.